# Border not appearing on hover in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Here's my code:

```
<button class="text-center hover:border-b-2 hover:border-black">Home</button>
```

I'm using TailwindCSS. When I remove the `hover:` before the `border-b-2` it works well, with a gray border normally and a black border appearing on hover. But once I add the `hover` prefix, the border disappears. Is my code correct?

Comment: It works fine on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/aQKQxQOJxY unless that is not the behavior you expected. If the play example shows what you want and your local project doesn't then you have a config issue.

Comment: Yes that is the desired behavior. I might have a config issue

Answer (score 0):

Per [Tailwindcss default variants reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants#default-variants-reference)

Tailwind css does not include all variants for all utilities by default.

Howerver Tailwind css allow you add more pseudo class in tailwind.config.js

```
// tailwind.config.js
variants: {
  extend: {
    borderStyle: ['responsive', 'hover'],
    borderWidth: ['responsive', 'hover'],
    },
},
```

So, this config border-* will be active.